# Identify this spider from Bangladesh

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Location: Jahangirnagar university, Savar, Bangladesh
[image: unidentified spider]

EDIT: [Here](https://youtu.be/52lSx_yl45A) is the video from which image is taken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It  is a [jumping spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumping_spider). Could be Genus *[Epocilla sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epocilla)* .

Jumping spiders have their posterior lateral eyes placed high up the cephalothorax and the rest three pairs in a [typical arrangement](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Salticidae_Male_Anterior_annotated.jpg) as observed in your specimen.

[image]

An image of *Epocilla sp*. from [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Epocilla.jpg).

Your specimen more closely resembles the [*E. calcarata*](http://www.jumping-spiders.com/php/tax_drawings.php?id=1323) .

Comment: Epocilla calcarata? http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1265/1229102333_2d73378d43.jpg

Comment: I can't assure. Not an Arachnologist myself, I think an expert can shade some light.

Answer (score 2):

Accurate Spider identification to species level is done by viewing the tiny structures of their anatomy under a microscope examining the spider’s reproductive organs. To find out which family your spider belongs to comes with experience. Helpful in identification are the eyes of the spider and they are not visible in this photograph. How many does it have? How are they arranged? How does each eye’s size compare to those around it? Here is a helpful link to some rules for identification. Good luck!!

http://www.spiders.us/articles/identification/#spider-location

Comment: Here is a video. https://youtu.be/52lSx_yl45A

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your answer seems more like a comment and does not fit our standards for good answers (see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and take the [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour)) - this is not a common discussion forum, so if you cannot answer the question, you should not give an answer. As is, your answer is very likely to be down-voted or deleted. Please edit you question if you want to make a suggestion regarding the id of the spider or delete it if you do not have a suggestion. Thank you!